# Overlay Webpage on 3D Application?

Tags: opengl, directx, overlay, html

I'm looking for a free substitute for a library called Awesomium, that would allow me to display a local html page on top of a rendered openGL scene, such that the user could interact with the webpage (ie. click buttons), but also interact with the scene, when the mouse is no longer on top of the web page window.

Any suggestions? Or anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: Awesomium sounds pretty awesome.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty ... awesomeium. But you have to license it for commercial uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Webkit to render to a [bitmap/texture](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/).  Map mouse/keyboard input to the displayed texture and hand that off to Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but in addition to what you've already accepted, there is another open source project along the lines of Awesomium being developed for use in the Ogre engine, which may or may not be useful / relevant: Berkelium - http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=54484